# Community Licenses - Limit of custom objects

Tags: licenses, community

The documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) says 10 custom objects per license.

I have managed to assign more than 10 to a profile using Customer Community License and also was able to query and display data on VF page for more than 10 custom objects.

Does anyone know what SF mean by "10 custom objects per license"? Is that `10 * number of licenses` in your org or is there any other meaning behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit is 10 custom objects per profile per community. There is no technical limit in place here AFAIK, it is a contractual limit so you may get a call from your Salesforce Account Executive at some point.

Comment: 1) What if a customer wants to expose an appexchange app that requires more than 10 custom objects?
2) That puts customers back on their project plans
3) Is there a possibility to increase that "contractual" limit by contacting SF, and are there any additional fees for that?

Comment: @greenstork Does this limit include ISV and Partner apps? e.g. if I use Docsign that needs 6 custom objects to work.

Comment: @codeulike the 10 custom objects limit does not include installed apps.

Comment: any documentation reference to this ?

Comment: @Greenstork, do you have any reference material which i can refer to , to know whether installed packages' objects are not included in the custom object limit?

Comment: Installed Managed Packages are not included - see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Comment: What about unmanaged packages? are they excluded too?

Comment: No, unmanaged packages are not excluded from custom object limits since they are not considered to be part of a separate ISV app.