# Salesforce "Customer Community" license, custom object limit

Tags: community

The salesforce documentation regarding custom object limit states  - 10 custom objects per license (custom objects in managed packages don’t count towards this limit) as per the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US). Does this mean that a developer who is creating an app (which will be distributed as a managed package) for "Customer Community" user can only have only 10 custom objects?
Or
Does this mean that for a "Customer Community" user the sum of all custom objects in all the apps have to be 10?

Also since it states that custom objects in managed package are not counted in this limit, can a developer have more than 10 custom objects if the application is distributed via a managed package?

Even though the [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17609/community-licenses-limit-of-custom-objects) states that this is a contractual limitation rather than a technical and installed packages do not count toward this limit, I just want to be sure