# Salesforce Community License Limits

Tags: community

I want to know all the limits related to Community License like 
No Of Custom Objects etc. Can anyone share me some links.

Regards

Comment: Google is your friend. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Hi Robin. I know Google is my friend. But i also want to know some extra, if anyone has any experience in community implementation.

Comment: @Sid Here is another [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html) from Salesforce where you can find more details on Community Licenses.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding commnity license limits visit this link. It may be helpfull:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html

The documentation here ":https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US" says 10 custom objects per license.
If you would like to use more than 10 custom objects, you will have to contact your account executive to work out the pricing.
fore more infomoration go thorogh this link.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/17628