# Force.com License query

Tags: force.com, licenses

For force.com licenses, we have a limit of 10 custom objects.Suppose i install an app from Appexchange or any managed/unmanaged package on my org.This package contains custom objects and my force.com user has permission to access contents of that package.

Now, the custom objects present in the package, would be counted against the limit of this user license or would they be excluded since they are a part of the package?

Answer (score 2):

The limit is not a technical limit as Salesforce will sell access to more custom objects in batches of 10.

Custom objects in Managed Packages are not counted against this limit. See [Community licence types](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US)

> Custom Objects
>   10 custom objects per license (custom objects in managed packages don’t count towards this limit)

This previous [question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17609/community-licenses-limit-of-custom-objects/17628#17628) here explains it too.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your response.Just want to know if this exemption is for unmanaged packages also or not

Comment: I really think it is just managed packages, so AppExchange tools will be fine, but I don't think unmanaged packages will be included as the wording looks quite specific.